# Is there any way I can remove \n from inner html inside a div?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to remove the `\n` inside a `div` element but nothing seems to work.

I tried using the methods `html(String)` and `text(String)` but the `\n` remains

```
<div class="line number1 index1 alt1">
 \n
 1
 \n
</div>
<div class="line number2 index2 alt2">
\n
 2
 \n
</div>
<div class="line number3 index3 alt1">
 \n
 3
 \n
</div>
```

Is there any way this could be done?

Thank you

Comment: Please post a [mcve] - and also reduce the size of your sample input - you don't need to demonstrate the same thing 6 times.

Comment: Show some view of how you see your problem. Do you see the `\n` in the page?

Comment: The \n in not shown in the page but it leads to a div with larger height than the desired.(The \n is shown in the debugger)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.replaceAll()` method for this by using a simple regex?

`htmlString = htmlString.replaceAll("\\n","");`

Comment: Doesnt it should be like this? `htmlString = htmlString.replaceAll("\n","");`

Comment: no because you will need to escape it as well right?

Comment: I tried  eleme.html(eleme.html().replaceAll("\\n","")); but the \n remains

Comment: then try with simple \n

Comment: It doesn't seem to work neither with simple \n nor with \\n

Comment: hey just printout what is in your html and update it here.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this script to your html file. It will take a text from each element with `class="line"`, count how many `\n` happens in it and after removing it.

**Script:**

```
String.prototype.count = function(s1) { 

    return (this.length - this.replace(new RegExp(s1,"g"), '').length) / s1.length;
}


$('.line').each(function(){

    let happens, i; 
    happens = $(this).text().count('\\n');

    for (i = 0; i < happens; i++) {
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace('\\n',''));
    }
});
```

Comment: Jsoup will not run any JavaScript, so this will not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Open Source Library MgntUtils (written by me) that has `TextUtils.formatStringToPreserveIndentationForHtml` one of the things it does - it replaces all '`\n`' with '`<br>`' This may be useful to you. Here is a link to the method's javadoc: [formatStringToPreserveIndentationForHtml](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/TextUtils.html#formatStringToPreserveIndentationForHtml-java.lang.String-). The library may be taken as [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils) or from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) (Including source code and Javadoc). Here is a link to the article about the library: [MgntUtils Open Source Java library](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/)